# Unix sed - changing contents inside HTML tags with a specific ID

Tags: html, bash, unix, sed

I have a file with the following contents:

```
<h1 id="name">John Smith</h1>
<h2 id="customer-id">192238</h2>
<h3 id="current-date">Thu 13 Apr 2017</h3>
```

How would I go about using sed to replace only the contents inside the tags based on the tag id?

In pseudo code:

1. Find the matching ID inside the file
2. Find the closing bracket `>` just after the ID name
3. Replace everything until the opening bracket `<` with `foo`

Note that this has to be done with `sed`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/19068

Comment: Better to provide a sample of the expected output

Comment: General HTML cannot be parsed with regular expressions. One may use regular expression if and only if the HTML is produced by a tool under one's control. You must defined _both_ the input format and the expected output. See the comment by user @Quentin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clarify what is the expected output.
You might want something like this (works with gnu sed):

```
cat <<EOF >file1
<h1 id="name">John Smith</h1>
<h2 id="customer-id">192238</h2>
<h3 id="current-date">Thu 13 Apr 2017</h3>
EOF

id="customer-id"
sed -r "/id=\"$id\"/ s/^<.[^>]*>/FOO/" file1
#Output
<h1 id="name">John Smith</h1>                                                                                                                                                   
FOO192238</h2>                                                                                                                                                                  
<h3 id="current-date">Thu 13 Apr 2017</h3>
```

Or maybe :

```
sed -r "/id=\"$id\"/ s/^<.[^>]*>/<FOO>/" file1
#Output of second line:
<FOO>192238</h2>
```

Or maybe :

```
sed -r "/id=\"$id\"/ s/(^<.*id=)[^>]*>/\1\"FOO\">/" <file1
#Output of second line:
<h2 id="FOO">192238</h2>
```

Comment: And expected _input_. General HTML cannot be parsed with regular expressions. One may use regular expression if and only if the HTML is produced by a tool under one's control.

Comment: @AlexP the particular regexes seems to work for the sample input file given by the OP. If the file is more "complex" those solutions may not work correcty.  I have include in the very beginning of my answer the expected input file.

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I ended up doing. I used: `sed -i -e "s/customer-id.>.*<\//customer-id\">$customer_id<\//g"` the only weakness is that `id="customer-id"` has to be the last thing before the closing brackets `>` but it's fine for my usecase

Comment: @Anurope Welcome. If you advise what is the expected output we can finetune the regex required.